# Which can be true? The importance of + Ving or the importance of + ADJ + Noun

Tags: grammar, adjectives, gerunds, present-participles

I am confused about the sentence below. Which structure  is used:  importance of + Ving or the importance of + ADJ + Noun ?

> In recently years, there has been growing awareness of **the importance of preserving** the world's  biological diversity.

Comment: What are you really asking?  Whether *preserving* is acting as an adjective here? No, it isn’t.  It’s a gerund.

Comment: Yes, I thought that preserving is acting as an adj.

Comment: You might be interested in [our sister-site for English learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object of the preposition *of* here is the entire gerund phrase “preserving the world’s biological diversity”, and “the world’s biological diversity” is the direct object of *preserving*.

We can’t have adjectives working as prepositional objects. Since that makes *preserving* is a gerund, it is here functioning as a noun, although it still has verbal properties like having its own object.

There is nothing that *preserving* is acting as a modifier for, either. It’s the head of its own VP (verb phrase).  [Here’s the full parse](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html):

```
(S (PP In
       (NP recent years))
   ,
   (S (NP there)
      (VP has
          (VP been
              (NP (NP growing awareness)
                  (PP of
                      (NP (NP the importance)
                          (PP of
                              (S (VP preserving
                                     (NP (NP the world 's)
                                         biological diversity))))))))))
   .)
```

Oh, and notice that you cannot say “in recently years”: it must be “in recent years”, because you need *recent* to be an adjective modifying *years*, and *recently* is an adverb.